# SonarQube issue resolve using @NotNull and @JsonProperty together

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm working on sonarQube issues in my company, on previously developed module I've to modify variable names as a part of fix. So I've applied `@JsonProperty` but I can't remove `@NotNull` as well. So my problem is `@JsonProperty` doing it's job but not null validation failing (THROWING EXCEPTION). Please help me with solution should I apply both annotation's. We are using spring mvc, and restful call to this dto. For now I don't want to make any validation in controller.

```
public class CustomerImpl extends Customer {

    @NotNull(message = "should not be null")
    @JsonProperty("customer_Id")
    private int customerId;

    @NotNull(message = "should not be null")
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "should not be null")
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception are you getting?

Comment: customerId, firstName, lastName should not be null, validation exception

Comment: Hiee Can someone please help me?